# Is it a right way to use Ivy compiler in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ivy

I want to setup angular project using Ivy compiler. But Unfortunately little documentation that`s why i am not able to decide.

Comment: For Angular 2 or later versions; instead, use the [angular] tag.

Comment: Interesting reading on the implementation: https://blog.angularindepth.com/inside-ivy-exploring-the-new-angular-compiler-ebf85141cee1

Comment: Ivy is not ready. It should be in Angular 8. Wait for the next version, and it will have instructions.

Comment: Thanks for quick response

Comment: In Angular 6, the Angular team introduced their third rendering engine called Ivy. So that's why I am confused. But I will wait for Angular 8 version .

Comment: Hi Jonathan I have followed your link and create 1 demo app with ivy it's work fine and also reduced file size . Is it useful to use ivy engine with Angular 7 version ?